# TraceId propagation

Tags: python, opentracing

I am getting TraceId from a different system in the form of Aws S3 metadata. Is there any way to use the same traceId and start a new span using opentracing? I know we can start span as `span = tracer.start_span(operation_name=operation, child_of=extracted_context)` but how can I create `extracted_context` from a custom traceId field?

Please note that this traceId I am receiving is not in `traceId:spanId:x:y` format but just a unique Id like `CFDA4D7D-D9C8-413A-86F8-39FEE773FD5E`